# AWS-SDK: RequestTimeTooSkewed in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, amazon-s3, time, aws-sdk

I'm developing an Angular 5/Ionic 3 app. The user can view and upload files to s3 directly from the frontend through credentials got from backend.  To upload from backend is not an option in our case. I'm usin AWS-SDK-2.224.1

The S3 funcionaties of this application includes putObject, listObjects and deleteObject. It works correctly in the desktop and, at principle, at mobile phones. I've tested it on Chrome and Android.

The problem begins when the time of Android is wrong. In this case S3 funcionalities stays not avaiable  and I get an error which says:

```
RequestTimeTooSkewed: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.
```

We cannot control if the time in user's device is correct. For example, here in Brazil we have DST. Recently we've got problems involving Android automatic time changing in DST and now my Android don't changes the automatically. So I need to set it manually. But when I do it S3 fails.

How could I use S3 in the bowser whithout even with system time being wrong?

Comment: S3 uses GMT, so *in theory*,Time Zone shouldn't matter.  But in reality - you're correct.  You *cannot* control the time in the user's device.  If the system time (with respect to GMT) is wrong - then you won't be able to authenticate with S3.  You need to find a different way to authenticate :(

Comment: What about enabling [the option to correct for clock skew](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#correctClockSkew-property)?